# Using reduce to compare in js

Tags: javascript, math, reduce

I have a simple question that I don't understand.. So I have these two data sets

```
const test = [
    {
        Shift: 2,
        Shift1: 211
    }, 
    {
        Shift: 15,
        Shift1: 111
    },
    {
        Shift: 25,
        Shift1: 111
    }
];


const data = [
    {
        value1: 163,
        value2: 175
    },
    {
        value1: 163,
        value2: 176
    },
    {
        value1: 165,
        value2: 176
    }
];


console.log(test.reduce((a, b) => (a.value1 + a.value2) > (b.value1 + b.value2) ? a : b));
```

When displaying test set, it results:
    Shift:25, Shift1: 111

whereas I expected to get:

```
Shift:2, Shift1: 211.
```

However when displaying data set, it returns

```
value1:165, value2: 175
```

as I expected... why is that?

Comment: Your `test` objects don't even have `value1` or `value2` properties, so you are comparing a lot of `NaN`s here.

Comment: test has no "value1" or "value2" fields

Comment: copy this into jsfiddle and you will get his problem guys.....`reduce()` method will reduce the array to a single entry. Thats why you get just the last entry. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Why don't you start by explaining what you are trying to accomplish in words. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: @messerbill I know what `reduce()` does. OPs code seems geared towards the `data` array, but not for `test`.

Comment: sorry all, this was my first question asking in Stackoverflow. Ill keep that in mind in future questions. Thanks

Comment: **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47755492/edit)** this question with clarifications

Comment: @Sirko i was talking to OP

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong key name on the reduce for the `test` constant... (e.g `value1` and `value2`) instead of `Shift` and `Shift1`.

Try this instead - it'll get your required output (just tried in Chrome's Inspect Element)

```
console.log(test.reduce((a, b) => (a.Shift + a.Shift1) > (b.Shift + b.Shift1) ? a : b));
```

Returns...

```
{Shift: 2, Shift1: 211}
```

Your key names aren't very descriptive though - nor are your object names. Try and think about how your code will look to you in six months' time when you've forgotten why you did what you did - or similarly if someone else looks at your code and thinks the same.

Hope this helps.